# Installing pip on Mac OS error - Permission denied: '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip'

Tags: python

I am trying to install Django, the first step is to install pip on Mac OS, but I'm getting an error.

**Command:**

```
python get-pip.py
```

but got the following error:

```
Permission denied: '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip'
```

Answer (score 6):

Try

```
sudo easy_install pip
```

it works

Comment: But then isn't pip owned by root and you always need to sudo for everything after that?