# Can anyone help? Getting "[Errno 13] Permission denied" when I try to install pip on Mac

Tags: python, pip, installation

Thank you in advance for any guidance (I've heard mixed advice on sudo command?). Here is the script from Terminal:

> running install
>   Checking .pth file support in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/
>   error: can't create or remove files in install directory

The following error occurred while trying to add or remove files in the
installation directory:

> [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/test-easy-install-85961.pth'

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Installing pip on Mac OS gives Permission denied: '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24098736/installing-pip-on-mac-os-gives-permission-denied-library-python-2-7-site-pack)

Answer (score 4):

You need to be root in order to write inside /Library, therefore you have to issue the install command as root:

```
sudo <command>
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for weighing in. That worked but shortly after I tried to install a Twitter library using $ pip install python-twitter and I got a permissions error. I used $ sudo pip install python-twitter and got this back:
The directory '/Users/HannahLastName/Library/Caches/pip/http' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and the cache has been disabled. Please check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.

Are my permissions off or something? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Do you think HomeBrew would be a better alternative than running through OS X if I keep getting permissions errors?

Answer (score 0):

Well "sudo" should have worked,

```
sudo pip install <package-name>
```

Secondly make sure your pip is updated

```
sudo pip install --upgrade pip
```

After running PIP through sudo you might get a warning about *"directory is not owned by current user"* can be ignored.